# Azure function stopped working, restarting every 30 minutes and after some time starts working as it should

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-5

I will try to explain everything that happened in the last month or so.

Azure function in question is a timer trigger that is working on a crone job every 2 minutes.

On Saturday 13th of May, at around 6am azure function finishes last trigger and instead of waiting 2 minutes for a restart it gives us this

> Stopped the listener
> '"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.SingletonListener"' for
> function '"XFunction"'

Then we get

> Job has stopped

Then

> Host lock lease acquired by instance ID 'some id'.

After this every half an hour for the next 20 or so days we keep getting this message

> Worker process started and initialized.

Then on the 21th of June at 4am we get this

> The Dashboard setting is no longer supported. See https://aka.ms/functions-dashboard for details.

Then

> Initializing Warmup Extension.
>
> Initializing Host. OperationId: '9b4de1a5-b06d-4351-be12-80345579a1a0'.

And so on and so on, basically it starts to work normally, without any interference.

Note: All of this happened without any developer doing anything on azure, we noticed this after it has been restarted and now are looking into it.

My question is what happened, could there be some manual (restart or redeploy) action which would restart the azure function correctly and how to prevent this in future.